# How to click on frame if its generating every time after page reload

Tags: imacros

I have code where FRAME NAME always different after reloading the page, how i can check for frame name with javascript

```
FRAME NAME="uimefgj4gktz"
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:ig-kg-Zb-Fh
```

Html code of the page

```
<div id=":6" aria-selected="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;" role="tab" class="a-lg"><div class="ig-kg-Zb-Fh">URL</div></div>
<div class="ig-kg-Zb-Fh">URL</div>
```

Comment: Easy. Extract the DIV above that one. Extract the frame name with split('name="')[1] and get the rest of the data... The full code is long to write and with no HTML from your side this is the best u get.

Comment: @macroscripts Hi i added html code, would be great if you could show the example. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id=":6" aria-selected="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;" role="tab" class="a-lg"><div class="ig-kg-Zb-Fh">URL</div></div>
<div class="ig-kg-Zb-Fh">URL</div>
```

Where is attribute name="uimefgj4gktz" inside this?

If there is such attribute you  can do following

```
iimPlay(someMacro);

var data=iimGetLastExtract();

var fname=data.split('name="')[1].split('"')[0].trim();
```

The someMacro variable u have to figure out yourself. It's home work.